# edit wordpress plugin to make it front end

Tags: php, wordpress, canvas

i am using a plugin for drawing on wordpress called [drawblog](https://wordpress.org/plugins-wp/drawblog/) which embed a drawing canvas at the bottom of the post page "wp-admin/post-new.php" [image]

i am tring to find a front end solution for the drawing part to enable my users to draw without the dashboard i tried this [tutorial](https://gaurangdabhi.wordpress.com/2014/05/30/frontend-posting-without-using-plugin-wordpress/) to make a front end posting page,it worked but it only makes a form for posting and the drawing canvas does not appear.
another thing i tried was to edit the drawing plugin and make a short code to use it in a page on the website

"add_shortcode("draw-form3", "drawblog_post_form");"

and it made the canvas appear but without the ability of drawing.
following is the file of the plugin "drawblog/drawblog.php" which i tried to edit

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: DrawBlog
Plugin URI: http://drawblog.com/
Description: A WordPress plugin that allows commenters to draw a picture.
Version: 0.90
Author: Randy Tayler
Author URI: http://randytayler.com
License: GPL

*/
global $drawblog_db_version;
global $drawblog_form_complete;
global $drawblog_post_form_complete;
$drawblog_db_version = "0.63";
/* Runs when plugin is activated */
register_activation_hook(__FILE__,'drawblog_install'); 

// add_filter('comment_text', 'drawblog_add_image_to_comment');
// add_action('comment_form', 'drawblog_comment_form');
add_action('comment_post', 'drawblog_save_image');
add_filter('the_content', 'drawblog_add_image_to_post');
add_action('save_post', 'drawblog_save_post_image' );
add_action('edit_form_advanced', 'drawblog_post_form' );

/////tarek////

add_shortcode("draw-form3", "drawblog_post_form");


///////////

function drawblog_install() {
    global $drawblog_db_version;
    add_option("drawblog_db_version", $drawblog_db_version);
    if (!is_dir(WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/drawblog/images')){
        wp_mkdir_p(WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/drawblog/images', 755);
    }
    if (!get_option("drawblog_canvas_title")) add_option("drawblog_canvas_title", __('Click here to draw a picture to include in your comment.'));
    if (!get_option("drawblog_hint_text1")) add_option("drawblog_hint_text1",  __('Click on one of the images above to draw on it, or start from a blank canvas.'));
    if (!get_option("drawblog_hint_text2")) add_option("drawblog_hint_text2",  __('Include this picture with my comment.'));
    if (!get_option("drawblog_warning1")) add_option("drawblog_warning1",  __("This will copy over what you've already drawn. Are you sure?"));
    if (!get_option("drawblog_warning2")) add_option("drawblog_warning2",  __('Are you sure you want to clear your drawing?'));
    if (!get_option("drawblog_canvas_width")) add_option("drawblog_canvas_width", 400);
    if (!get_option("drawblog_canvas_height")) add_option("drawblog_canvas_height", 300);
    if (!get_option("drawblog_post_classname")) add_option("drawblog_post_classname", drawblog_determine_classname());  
    if (!get_option("drawblog_show_canvas")) add_option("drawblog_show_canvas", true);
    if (!get_option("drawblog_default_bg")) add_option("drawblog_default_bg", '');
}

function drawblog_add_image_to_comment($comment_text){
    global $comment; 
    $drawblog_image = drawblog_get_image($comment->comment_ID);
    if (($drawblog_image) && 
        (is_file( WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/drawblog/images/' . $drawblog_image)) && 
        (getimagesize(  WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/drawblog/images/' . $drawblog_image) !== false)){            
            $comment_text = "<img src=\"". content_url(). '/drawblog/images/'.$drawblog_image."\" class=\"drawblogimage\"><br>".$comment_text;
    }
    return $comment_text;
}

function drawblog_add_image_to_post($post_text){
    global $post; 
    $drawblog_image = drawblog_get_post_image($post->ID);
    if (($drawblog_image) && 
        (is_file( WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/drawblog/images/' . $drawblog_image)) && 
        (getimagesize(  WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/drawblog/images/' . $drawblog_image) !== false)){            
            $post_text = "<img src=\"". content_url(). '/drawblog/images/'.$drawblog_image."\" class=\"drawblogimage\"><br>".$post_text;
    } 
    return $post_text;
}

function drawblog_get_image($comment_id){
    global $wpdb;
    $meta = get_comment_meta($comment_id, 'drawblog_image');
    return $meta[0];
}

function drawblog_get_post_image($post_id){
    global $wpdb;
    $meta = get_post_meta($post_id, 'drawblog_image');
    return $meta[0];
}

function drawblog_comment_form(){
    global $drawblog_form_complete;
    if (!$drawblog_form_complete){
        echo drawblog_add_canvas();
        $drawblog_form_complete = true;
    }
}

function drawblog_post_form(){
    global $drawblog_post_form_complete;
    global $post;
    global $image_exists;
    $drawblog_image = drawblog_get_post_image($post->ID);
    if (($drawblog_image) && 
        (is_file( WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/drawblog/images/' . $drawblog_image)) && 
        (getimagesize(  WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/drawblog/images/' . $drawblog_image) !== false)){
            $image_exists = 'true';
        } else {
            $image_exists = 'false';
        }
    if (!$drawblog_post_form_complete){
        echo drawblog_add_post_canvas();
        $drawblog_post_form_complete = true;
    }
}

function drawblog_save_image($comment_id){
    global $wpdb;
    if ($_POST['drawblog_include_pic'] == true){
        $data = $_POST['drawblog_picture'];
        $raw_data = str_replace(' ','+',$data);
        $filtered_data=substr($raw_data, strpos($raw_data, ",")+1);
        $data = base64_decode($filtered_data);
        $new_image = uniqid($comment_id.'_').'.png';
        $fp = fopen(WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/drawblog/images/'.$new_image, 'wb' );
        fwrite( $fp, $data);
        fclose( $fp );
        if (is_file(WP_PLUGIN_DIR . "/drawblog/icons/dbwm.png")){
            $im = imagecreatefrompng(WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/drawblog/images/'.$new_image);
            $src = imagecreatefrompng(WP_PLUGIN_DIR . "/drawblog/icons/dbwm.png");
            list($wm_width, $wm_height) = getimagesize(WP_PLUGIN_DIR . "/drawblog/icons/dbwm.png");
            imagecopy($im, $src, get_option('drawblog_canvas_width')-$wm_width, get_option('drawblog_canvas_height') - $wm_height, 0, 0, $wm_width, $wm_height);
            imagepng($im, WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/drawblog/images/'.$new_image);
        } 
        add_comment_meta($comment_id, 'drawblog_image', $new_image);
    }
}
function drawblog_save_post_image($post_id){
    global $wpdb;
    if ($_POST['drawblog_include_pic'] == true){
        $data = $_POST['drawblog_picture'];
        $raw_data = str_replace(' ','+',$data);
        $filtered_data=substr($raw_data, strpos($raw_data, ",")+1);
        $data = base64_decode($filtered_data);
        $new_image = uniqid('p'.$post_id.'_').'.png';
        $fp = fopen(WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/drawblog/images/'.$new_image, 'wb' );
        fwrite( $fp, $data);
        fclose( $fp );
        if (is_file(WP_PLUGIN_DIR . "/drawblog/icons/dbwm.png")){
            $im = imagecreatefrompng(WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/drawblog/images/'.$new_image);
            $src = imagecreatefrompng(WP_PLUGIN_DIR . "/drawblog/icons/dbwm.png");
            list($wm_width, $wm_height) = getimagesize(WP_PLUGIN_DIR . "/drawblog/icons/dbwm.png");
            imagecopy($im, $src, get_option('drawblog_canvas_width')-$wm_width, get_option('drawblog_canvas_height') - $wm_height, 0, 0, $wm_width, $wm_height);
            imagepng($im, WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/drawblog/images/'.$new_image);
        } 
        delete_post_meta($post_id, 'drawblog_image');
        add_post_meta($post_id, 'drawblog_image', $new_image);
    } else {
        delete_post_meta($post_id, 'drawblog_image');
    }
}

function drawblog_check_options(){  
    //new options pose a little trouble on upgrade. This'll force them to update if the installation trick didn't work 
    if (!get_option("drawblog_hint_text1")) add_option("drawblog_hint_text1",  __('Click on one of the images above to draw on it, or start from a blank canvas.'));
    if (!get_option("drawblog_hint_text2")) add_option("drawblog_hint_text2",  __('Include this picture with my comment.'));
    if (!get_option("drawblog_warning1")) add_option("drawblog_warning1",  __("This will copy over what you've already drawn. Are you sure?"));
    if (!get_option("drawblog_warning2")) add_option("drawblog_warning2",  __('Are you sure you want to clear your drawing?'));

    if (get_option("drawblog_hint_text1")=='') update_option("drawblog_hint_text1",  __('Click on one of the images above to draw on it, or start from a blank canvas.'));
    if (get_option("drawblog_hint_text2")=='') update_option("drawblog_hint_text2",  __('Include this picture with my comment.'));
    if (get_option("drawblog_warning1")=='') update_option("drawblog_warning1",  __("This will copy over what you've already drawn. Are you sure?"));
    if (get_option("drawblog_warning2")=='') update_option("drawblog_warning2",  __('Are you sure you want to clear your drawing?'));

}

function drawblog_add_canvas(){
    drawblog_check_options();
    global $post;
    if (get_option('drawblog_api_key')!=''){
        $ch = curl_init('http://drawblog2.com/auth.php');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        $postfields = 'apikey='.get_option('drawblog_api_key').'&domain='.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        $postfields .='&theme='.get_stylesheet(); // if you're using the api, I need your theme
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        echo curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
    }
    $width = get_option('drawblog_canvas_width');
    $height = get_option('drawblog_canvas_height');
    include "drawblog_canvas.php";
}

function drawblog_add_post_canvas(){
    drawblog_check_options();
    if (get_option('drawblog_api_key')!=''){
        $ch = curl_init('http://drawblog.com/auth.php');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        $postfields = 'apikey='.get_option('drawblog_api_key').'&domain='.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        $postfields .='&theme='.get_stylesheet(); // if you're using the api, I need your theme
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        echo curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
    }
    $width = get_option('drawblog_canvas_width');
    $height = get_option('drawblog_canvas_height');
    include "drawblog_post_canvas.php";
}

function drawblog_determine_classname(){
    $themedir = get_stylesheet_directory();
    $theme = get_stylesheet(); // I wish this function was called get_theme(), but whatever
    switch ($theme){        
        case 'custom-community':
            $postclass = 'post-content';
            break;
        case 'inferno-mf':
            $postclass = 'post';
            break;
        case 'easel':
        case 'eclipse':
        case 'ifeature':
            $postclass = 'entry';
            break;
        case 'responsive':
            $postclass = "post-entry";
            break;
        case 'mantra':
        case 'pagelines':
        case 'pinboard':
        case 'twentyeleven':
        case 'twentyten':
        case 'twentytwelve':
        default:
            $postclass = "entry-content";
            break;
    }
    return $postclass;
}

function get_image_data($img){  
    $domain_bits = parse_url($img);
    $domain = $domain_bits['host'];
    $filename = $domain_bits['path'];
    if ($domain == $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) {       
        $file = $img;
    } else {
        $file = plugins_url().'/drawblog/drawblog_safeimage.php?img='.urlencode($img);
    }
    $img_info = getimagesize($img);
    if ($img_info !== false){
        echo json_encode(array($file,$img_info[0], $img_info[1]));
    } else echo '';
}

if ( is_admin() ){
    add_action('admin_menu', 'drawblog_admin_menu');

    function drawblog_admin_menu() {
        add_options_page('DrawBlog', 'DrawBlog', 'administrator', 'drawblog', 'drawblog_settings_page');
    }

    function drawblog_check_api_key($apikey){
        $ch = curl_init('http://drawblog.com/validate.php');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        $postfields = 'apikey='.$apikey.'&domain='.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $retval = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $retval;
    }

    function drawblog_update_options($values){
        $title = $values['drawblog_canvas_title'];  
        $hint1 = $values['drawblog_hint_text1'];    
        $hint2 = $values['drawblog_hint_text2'];
        $warning1 = $values['drawblog_warning1'];   
        $warning2 = $values['drawblog_warning2'];                   
        $width = intval($values['drawblog_canvas_width']);
        $height = intval($values['drawblog_canvas_height']);
        $show_canvas = $values['drawblog_show_canvas'];
        if ($values['drawblog_default_bg']) $default_bg = $values['drawblog_default_bg'];
        if ($width<=0) return __('Canvas width'); //returns other than 'success', below, indicate a field with an error. Canvases cannot be negative or zero values.
        if ($height<=0) return __('Canvas height');
        if (($values['drawblog_api_key']!='') && (!(drawblog_check_api_key($values['drawblog_api_key']) == 1))) return __('API key is invalid or expired. Visit <a href="http://drawblog.com/purchase.php">DrawBlog.com</a> to purchase or renew an API key.');
        update_option('drawblog_api_key', $values['drawblog_api_key']); 
        update_option('drawblog_canvas_width', $width);     
        update_option('drawblog_canvas_height', $height);
        update_option('drawblog_canvas_title', $title);
        update_option('drawblog_hint_text1', $hint1);
        update_option('drawblog_hint_text2', $hint2);
        update_option('drawblog_warning1', $warning1);
        update_option('drawblog_warning2', $warning2);
        update_option('drawblog_post_classname', $values['post_class_name']);
        update_option('drawblog_show_canvas', $show_canvas);
        update_option('drawblog_default_bg', $default_bg);
        return 'success';
    }
    function drawblog_settings_page() {
        include "drawblog_admin.php";
    }
}
?>
```

now what is the best solution to get drawblog plugin to work on new page ?

Answer (score 0):

There are some plugins allowing posting from the frontend: https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/wordpress-post-frontend-plugins/
It might work with your drawing thing.

Hope it helps,

Ondrej

Comment: yes it creates a posting form but it does not bring the drawing canvas of drawblog with it